# Replacing square.gif

Tags: links-list

I have set up a simple list of links.  When I select Summary View, it add bullets next to the list.  The bullets are gray and I want to change the color.  I have gone to images/square.gif and replaced the file, reset IIS, even rebooted the server, ran the search and I still am unable to get the gold colored bullet to show up.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should not change any out-of-the-box SharePoint files, not only XMLs/XSLs or JS files, but images either. Your changes will / might be overridden by upcoming service packs / cumulative updates. Instead of this you can add a Script Editor web part to the page and update the `src` attribute of the bullet images via `JQuery` to refer to the right image file you deployed to the file system or store in a SharePoint document library.